# jquery output id display as [object object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var str = prompt("What is your name?");
var str1=$(str).html('<b>'+str+'</b>');
alert(str1);
```

By above code I'm getting `[object object]` as output ,. please help

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: jQuery works on HTML/DOM and not on arbitrary strings...

Answer (score 2):

```
alert(str1.html());
```

is what you are after.

each function in jquery returns a jquery object so

```
.html('<b>'+str+'</b>')
```

returns an object, not the text inside the element.

Comment: alert().text(); what should alert return? you mean alert(str1.text());

Comment: I think you mean `alert(str1.text());`

Comment: i need to convert prompt text into bold and display into textarea box

Comment: A standard textarea cannot have bold formatted text inside it unless you style all of its content to be bold

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's look up `html()` in the jQuery API:

- http://api.jquery.com/html/

It has two variations. If you pass an argument, the method signature is this:

```
.html( htmlString ) Returns: jQuery
```

So it returns a `jQuery` object. And objects don't have any interesting to show inside an alert. Now, what can you do with jQuery objects that represent a DOM node? Well, you can [read back their HTML code](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
alert(myNode.html());
```

... or you can [read their plain text value](http://api.jquery.com/text):

```
alert(myNode.text());
```

Now, let's look at your code:

```
var str = prompt("What is your name?");
```

Since [prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.prompt) returns either a string (if the user typed something and hit *OK*) or `null` (if the user hit *Cancel*), `str` will either be an arbitrary string or `null`.

```
var str1=$(str)
```

You are calling jQuery with an arbitrary string so you'll get an arbitrary jQuery object. If the user types `john` you'll run `$("john")`. That means: match any element that contains a `<john></john>` tag. If the user types `<h1>Hi</h1>` you'll *create* a first level title. And so on...

```
               .html('<b>'+str+'</b>');
```

Now you pick whatever you got in the first step and tell jQuery to change its HTML to some arbitrary content: `.html("<b>john</b>")` or `.html("<b><h1>Hi</h1></b>")`...

```
alert(str1);
```

... and we get nothing interesting so far ;-)

Comment: Alvaro, thanks for such a lengthy response!  I'm looking for something that converts a jQuery object into an html table with hyperlinks that drill down the methods and objects inside the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct because your are setting the HTML and then the function returns the jQuery object

```
var str1=$(str).html('<b>'+str+'</b>').html();
```

now str1 will have the HTML string.

Edit: 
But as DarthJDG pointed out correctly wrapping a string (the return value of `prompt()`) into a jQuery object and the stetting some HTML to it makes no real scense.

Comment: Try putting in a valid selector at the prompt and this could get a lot more interesting. :)

Comment: you are so right ;-). Never looked at this, only concentrated on the alert problem ^^

Comment: `$(obj).html(val).html() == val;`. So why not just do `str1 = '<b> + str + </b>; $(str).html(str1);`

Comment: i need to convert prompt text into bold and display into textarea box

Answer (score 0):

The statment `$(str).html('<b>'+str+'</b>');` is setting the `html` of `$(str)`, and then returning `$(str)` back from the call (for chaning purposes).

I've held back on suggesting a soluton because I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you be alittle more explicit in your question?

Comment: i need to convert prompt text into bold and display into textarea box

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and that is exactly what you should expect. By passing an argument to [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2), you're invoking the method that returns a [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) (i.e., an object).

If, instead, you want to return the (HTML) *value* of the element, you should `alert(str1.html())`, thus [invoking the method](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html1) which returns a [string](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#String).

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
alert($(str).html());
```

YOur code wasn't working because `$(str).html('<b>'+str+'</b>');` return a jquery object, not an string.

Cheers